# Plugin event in Slider Kartik extension for Yii2

Tags: javascript, yii2

I tried to use [this](http://demos.krajee.com/slider) extesion. All i want is reply example 6 from official [docs](https://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/) Thats what i did:

```
<?php echo Slider::widget([
'name'=>'rating_1',
  'value'=>7,
  'sliderColor'=>Slider::TYPE_GREY,
  'pluginEvents' => [
     "slide" => "function(slideEvt) { 
        $('#testVal').text(slideEvt.value); 
        }",
   ],
]);
?>
<span>Current Slider Value: <span id="testVal">3</span></span>
```

[image]
So as you can see on the picture, i can move slider, but value inside #testVal do not changing. What i did wrong?

Comment: are you sure there is only one `span` with the `id#testVal` ? your code works for me in the first go , make sure you dont have multiple spans with same id and look for any errors in console

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Yes, you right.  I have several span element. I changed their ids and its worked.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam in my HTML for ids i use my models attribute, so usually it looks like  id="<?php echo $value['strategy_title'] . "-release_date"; ?>". I tried to use the same to this js but got an error. https://imgur.com/a/m1eAIiY 

How to do it in right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that you have only a single span element with the id `testVal`, otherwise, it wouldn't work, there is nothing wrong with the script.

Secondly, remove the extra double-quotes `"` around the id part from the line

```
$('"<?php echo $value['strategy_title']?>"').text(slideEvt.value);
```

to

```
$('". $value['strategy_title']."').text(slideEvt.value);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51703216/how-to-pass-php-variable-to-pluginevent-config-slider-kartik-extension-for-yii2

Comment: @BrokenCoin , sorry i added the tags as is , just fixed check  again.